# android.os.DeadObjectException by Remote Service Application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Does anyone ever meet a "android.os.DeadObjectException" thrown by a
remote service in Android? The problem I met is, the transact method
in the service binder interface threw this exception to me.

I wrote a remote service, and called it through the service binder.
However, in the line of the binder interface (which is generated
automatically AIDL interface) "mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_open,
_data, _reply, 0);", it threw a "android.os.DeadObjectException" to
me.

I have read the definition of DeadObjectException, it says this
exception means "The object you are calling has died, because its
hosting process no longer exists.". However, I checked this with my
DDMS, and it showed the process of the remote service crashed.

So, is there any other possible reason to make this exception
happened? or could someone here tell me how to avoid this exception?